# Capturing / cloning packets arriving at a production server and using them to test a staging server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, socket.io, tcpdump

We have an application that is quite complex in production that involves real-time communications. The main components are, a Ruby on Rails application which responds to http requests and a socket-io server which handles the real-time comms part.

What I would like to do, is capture / clone the packets coming into production and use them to test updates to critical parts of our application on a staging system under "real" load without risking breaking production. I'm thinking that this could possibly be achieved in two ways.

**Option 1** - cloning production traffic on the fly and send it on to staging.

**Option 2** - Store and replay a sample of production traffic onto staging.

In both cases we'd probably need to ignore the responses from staging and instead log them or send them on to only select clients.

I've been investigating using some linux tools like tcpdump and tcpreplay to achieve this. It certainly seems possible but before I dive headfirst into this I wanted to check if anyone has done this before and what kind of approach they used.